Inductor and capacitor in parallel should not yield resultant current in phase w/ voltage
In Power Systems Analysis by Grainger and Stevenson, the authors state (p9): An adjustable capacitor in parallel with an inductive load... can be adjusted so that the leading current to the capacitor is exactly equal in magnitude to the component of current in the inductive load which is lagging the voltage by 90°. Thus, the resultant current is in phase with the voltage.
Shouldn't the resultant current just be zero?

Focus on my emphasis: "the component of current ... which is lagging".

I see now. Thank you so much for the clarification!

Yes. You were missing the care with which they wrote their words. That's all.

"Inductive load" here means a load with an overall inductive component to its current in addition to any in-phase current, not a purely inductive load. I.e. a phase angle between 0 and +90. This is describing power factor correction.

Not totally wrong but deceptive, as a reader might think that the inductive load is an inductor.
Maybe it is more clear when in context.

The "component of" is explicit to me; a new reader would be wise to focus on the vector nature of AC signals. This is a typical question present in chapters introducing such, so it should be clear in context -- or at clear as a textbook might be, which, to be fair, students often find wanting. But that's its own [writing] issue.
